# Telegram bot stop work with error: Asynchronous operation was still pending. - C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, telegram-bot

My bot worked excellent about 10 months and I didn't have any problem. I use `getUpdates` method for answer users but now I don't get any response and after the bot starts, I get this error

> "**An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending**."

I am using **telegram.net** library

Comment: At the first as
you if you don't write this    Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue); after bot.StartReceiving(); please add .

Secondly:
If Your bot doesn't send any MSG do under steps:
So, those who faces the problem "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL / TLS secure channel"

1. Update your system.

2. If you use .NET Framework 4.5, add this line somewhere before you initialize TelegramBotClient:

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

or target .NET Framework 4.6 and higher to use TLS 1.2 as default.

Answer (score 1):

At the first as you if you don't write this Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue); after bot.StartReceiving(); please add . Secondly: If Your bot doesn't send any MSG do under steps: So, those who faces the problem "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL / TLS secure channel" 1. Update your system. 2. If you use .NET Framework 4.5, add this line somewhere before you initialize TelegramBotClient: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; or target .NET Framework 4.6 and higher to use TLS 1.2 as default.